# FLYWAYDB exception while updating H2(2.1.210) and Flyway (8.5.0)dependencies

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, build, flyway

My maven build is failing while am updating the dependcy version of H2 and Flywaydb from 1.4.200 h2 to 2.1.210 and 6.4.4 to 8.5.0 flywaydb. Please find the error logs attached:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate()I
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate()I
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like there is a typo in the code calling Flyway `org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate()I`. There should not be a trailing 'I'.